# Ignore warnings for all pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode9, xcode9.2, podfile

I put `inhibit_all_warnings!` at the top of my pod file then ran `pod install` and still see warnings in XCode.

Update: I was able to get it to kinda work by cleaning the project after pod installing, however, I still see warnings sporadically.

Comment: If the problem was solved, delete the question, please.

Comment: I was hoping to help others as there wasnt much online about this.  How can I do that if I delete the question?